# Does my update only change the value of a column or its schema as well?

Tags: sql

I have something strange on my sql after removing whitespaces in sql 
using below keyword

```
update table set CompanyName = LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyName))
```

I think I just changed the content with that script. Is it correct to assume that I didn't change the properties of the column involved, so it has the same name and type?

Comment: What do you mean by “column property?

Comment: i mean i modify the column

Comment: because when i try to delete or edit on database in my view (asp) nothing but in database data is available

Comment: You mean whether you change the name of the column? No, you do not do that with this code. You would need an `ALTER TABLE` statement for that.

Comment: so is it right that i jut edit the data content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. An `update` command changes value(s) of record(s) involved and leaves the `column` type and name intact. So, your `CompanyName` will remain unchanged as a column, but its value will be updated.